# runFun over segments of a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to find the running sum over segments of a vector. I looked at the runSum function but couldn't make it work because first it requires an "n" that results in NA's for all values less than n.  And second I couldn't run it on pieces of the vector by combining it with a `sapply` and `split`.  A code like this for example wouldn't work: `sapply(split(x, by = y), runSum)`

x: is the vector I want to sum on after segmenting it or splitting it with y bins

```
x <- c(5,8,7,9,13,10,8,4,7,12,14,11,9,8,12,13,16,8,8,5,6,6,6,4,8,11,12,13,15,14)
y <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6)
```

I will demonstrate the desired result for the first 10 elements of the vector which is the first 2 bins and the first element of the 3rd bin in a variable called target bellow.

```
target <- c(5,13,20,29,13,23,31,35,42,12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `tapply` and `cumsum`:

```
tapply(x, y, cumsum)
# $`1`
# [1]  5 13 20 29
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 13 23 31 35 42 54
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 14 25 34 42 54
# 
# $`4`
# [1] 13 29 37
# 
# $`5`
# [1]  8 13 19 25 31 35
# 
# $`6`
# [1]  8 19 31 44 59 73
```

Use `unlist` to get a vector like your "target" vector.

Comment: Oh my, it was that easy?  Thanks Ananda

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use `cumsum` with `ave`:

```
> ave(x, y, FUN=cumsum)
#  [1]  5 13 20 29 13 23 31 35 42 54 14 25 34 42 54
# [16] 13 29 37  8 13 19 25 31 35  8 19 31 44 59 73
```